# Google map snapshot attribution

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I am using the GoogleMaps control ([Github page](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/)) in my Xamarin.Forms app.

I take a snapshot of the map to use as a static picture
in a view I navigate to from my map view.

From a legal standpoint:

Is it necessary to include the Google logo at the bottom and general attribution,
as when using the control in my map view?

Or can I cut the image generated by the snapshot, and display just a portion of it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about legal terms of use of a third-party service and not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my company, we had a list of map thumbnails and we didn't want to display the logo on each thumbnail.
We clipped the attribution text from each thumbnail, but then displayed the text "Map data: Google, Maxar Technologies" on the page footer. We referred to [this link](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide/), which says:

```
What does the attribution text need to say?

If you’re not using the text provided directly on Google Maps and Google Earth 
imagery, the text of your attribution must say the name “Google” and the relevant data 
provider(s), such as “Map data: Google, Maxar Technologies”.

You may customize the style and placement of the attribution text, as long as the text 
is legible to the average viewer or reader. Note that Google logos cannot be used in- 
line (for example, "These maps from [Google logo].")
```

Comment: So displaying “Map data: Google, Maxar Technologies” even in plain text to the user is still legally ok, right?

Comment: That is how we understood it. As long as Google gets the credit for the map data, they're happy.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you must use google logo because is a personal service.

if you want a service without a logo or ecc you must build it by your own

Comment: It's not a personal use, the application is freely available in the app stores, but is accompanying a paid product. Is it still the same?

Comment: yeah, if you make in general an app you must include the logo or the name of the service you use